# ERROR: opening '/usr/share/cacti/rra/localhost_cpu_system_14.rrd': No such file or directory

Tags: cpu, monitoring, cacti

I use cacti to monitor my system linux centos,
i monitored memory , load average but the graph of cpu usage is empty and i can't show it.
Please help me

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that you can get the cpu usage via the command line.
You can see the command used by cacti by clicking on System Utilities -> View Poller Cacti.
run this command via cli. If it works. Rebuild Poller Cache
If not troubleshoot your system and not cacti.